# i am writing a trigger to clone the related contact. can anyone help me to bulkify it,

Tags: trigger

```
   trigger AccountsRelationshipMapsTriggers on Accounts_Relationship_Map__c (after insert,after update) {
    public list<string> frmid;
    public list<string> toid;
      List<Accounts_Relationship_Map__c> accMap = [select id, name,From_Account__c,To_Account__c from Accounts_Relationship_Map__c where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate ){
        List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
        for(Accounts_Relationship_Map__c mapObj:accMap){
            if(mapObj != null){
                list<string> accid = new list<string>();
                accid.add(mapObj.From_Account__c) ;
                list<string> acc1id =new list<string>();
                acc1id.add(mapObj.To_Account__c);
                frmid = accid;
                toid = acc1id;
                system.debug(accid);
                system.debug(acc1id);
            }
        }
        List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = : frmid];
        for(Contact c : con){
            Contact conCopy = c.clone(false,true);
            conCopy.AccountId = toid[0];
            cons.add(conCopy);
            system.debug(conCopy);
            system.debug(toid[0]);
            system.debug(conCopy.AccountId);
        }
        insert cons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why use a trigger? why not use a visual flow?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is already bulkified in the basic sense i.e. the queries and DML are done once per trigger invocation and not once per record. But the trigger will break when the Accounts have large numbers of Contacts each, because, the maximum number of records that can be inserted in one transaction is 10,000. And if there is logic attached to the insert of Contact records, that logic may run into other governor limits before that limit is hit.

To be safe your trigger will need to run asynchronous code based on a  Contact record query so the row count is determinate. You also need to tie down the requirements or overall constraints more. As it stands, multiple updates will result in duplicate Contacts.

FYI, the code you posted should look more like this to get the Account Id value correct on the cloned Contacts:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Accounts_Relationship_Map__c (after insert, after update) {

    Map<Id, Id> fromTo = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for (Accounts_Relationship_Map__c arm : Trigger.new) {
        fromTo.put(arm.From_Account__c, arm.To_Account__c);
    }

    Contact[] clones = new Contact[] {};
    for (Contact c : [
        select Id, AccountId from Contact
        where AccountId = :fromTo.keySet()
    ) {
        Contact clone = c.clone(false, true);
        clone.AccountId = fromTo.get(clone.AccountId);
        clones.add(clone)
    }
    insert clones;
}
```